# Overlay in MapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

With a UIMapView it is possible to switch on "Show user location". This works fine. A little blue dot appears on the map. When I zoom in on the map a circle appears in the MapView around the blue dot.

Is this circle showing me the accuracy of the gps signal?

In my app I want to display the accuracy of the signal, is this already included in the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the standard behavior and yes the circle is showing you how accurate the signal is at that time, you will notice it starts big and then shrinks as accuracy increases.

Comment: That's wat I thought. Thank you very much for confirming.